# How can I multiply with the index?

Tags: python

I need to convert a number to base 10.
my input is from this form:1111(the number) 5(on which base) 10(to base).i wrote this code:

```
s=input()
(number, from_base, to_base) = s.split()
NumList=[number]
NumList.reverse()

i=0
sum=0


while (i< (index.from_base)):

  (i,pow(from_base,i),i+1) 
  sum=sum+i


print (sum)
```

I want to do: number^the from_base index.I tried also to do i**from_base\i^^from_base.
I tried also to add the command NumList.index() but it didn't work.

thank you!

Comment: You can actually use the `int` function to do that http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int which takes an extra base argument when needed.

Comment: @soulseekah... If the "to base" is always 10, is that right?

Comment: @BorrajaX, correct, although the OP's code does mention `to_base`, so...

Comment: int() has an optional second argument, an integer from 2 to 36, for base

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973685/python-homework-converting-any-base-to-any-base

Comment: i need to change it to the base the user want so i thought of, first convert to base 10 and then to the required base.I tried the function and this is the output:<class 'int'>. Should I include some special directory?

Answer (score 1):

The commenters have already addressed the deeper problem that you're trying to solve.

But the superficial question that you're asking can be best solved by using Python's enumerate:  Feed it a sequence of values and it returns a sequence of (index, value) pairs.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate